# how to add additional name-value pair in an existing flex object

Tags: apache-flex, object

folks, 
I have a question regarding adding additional name-value pairs to my existing object in Flex;

I have an object1 of Object Type 
and I declare a new object2 = object1 plus some extra name-value pairs,
is there a way to attach new name-value pairs to an existing object?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, object2 is a reference pointer to object1; therefore, changes to object2 affect object1:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class X extends Sprite
    {
        public function X()
        {
            var object1:Object = {a: "1", b: "2"};

            var object2:Object = object1;

            object2.c = 3;

            trace("Object 2:");
            for (var name:String in object2)
            {
                trace("Name: " + name + " = " + object2[name]);
            }

            trace("Object 1:");
            for (var name:String in object1)
            {
                trace("Name: " + name + " = " + object1[name]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...which outputs:

```
Object 2:
Name: a = 1
Name: c = 3
Name: b = 2
Object 1:
Name: a = 1
Name: c = 3
Name: b = 2
```

If you are asking whether an object or dynamic class may be cloned, you could use a function like this:

```
public function cloneObject(object:Object):Object
{
    var newObject:Object = {};

    for (var name:String in object)
    {
        newObject[name] = object[name];
    }

    return newObject;
}
```